# CSS placement example (Title, image, text and read more link)

Tags: css, html, slice

Say I have the following design to slice:

[image]

How I can slice it by NOT using absolute placement of divs and by not using table layouts (if they can be called layouts at all :))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be something like this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cFqDX/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="mainbody">
            <h1>Some title</h1>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Wbq.png" class="leftimage"/>
            <p>
                Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.
                Putting a lot of text here.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for the css.

```
.mainbody
{
    background-color:gray;
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
}

.leftimage
{
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

This gives me the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can either `float: left` or make a div around the text, which you give `display: inline-block`.

Comment: The second version with display: inline-block does not work :(

Comment: Oh, the second version works if I float left the image! Thanks!

Comment: It should if the image is on its own. If the image is in a block itself, that block should have `display: inline` or `inline-block` as well. But if it won't work for you, there's always the float. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make two div's. The left one containing the image with `float: left` and the one on the right with `float: right`. By doing so you'll have two "columns" next to each other.

But basically there are endless solutions to this....

Comment: Again a div for each text block and use the float option.

Comment: Please be more specific. How I should create the central column? Left and right columns are clear just will float right or left. So what about central??

Comment: The central column doesn't have to float. Check this JSfiddle that I made to explain my point: http://jsfiddle.net/MUpmD/

Answer (score 1):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCPCD/) here that I expect would work pretty nicely across browsers and is fairly easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks but why you use overflow: auto; for class .product?

Comment: Remove it and see what happens : )

Comment: Removed! Nothing happens :))! BTW I have pressed UPDATE button too!

Comment: Weird, it should cause the image in the first block to overlap the .product div, due to the .product div ignoring the floated elements. I use this as a sort of 'clearfix' rather than putting a semantically useless element into the container. EDIT: Wow, you're right. I've gotten ahead of myself here, haha. It appears it's not needed.